# Pandas - numpy and multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I am not too good about that yet but I dont know how to make this work:

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# initialize list of lists
data = [[1, 0], [4, 0], [8, 0]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Value', 'Test'])
df['Test'] = np.where(df['Value'].astype(int) >= 3 & df['Value'].astype(int) <= 7, 1, 2)
# print dataframe.
print(df)
```

I am getting error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Would appreciate any help on this case. What it is supposed to do is to change value in "Test" column based on two conditions regarding value in "Value" column

Comment: Use `np.where((df['Value'] >= 3) & (df['Value'] <= 7), 1, 2)`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing - silly me :( Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i was missing brackets ... should be like this:

```
df['Test'] = np.where((df['Value'].astype(int) >= 3) & (df['Value'].astype(int) <= 7), 1, 2)
```

Comment: You can also use `df["Value"].between(3, 7)`.